# sorting list view search data

Tags: java, android, eclipse

hi i am new android developer and want to know how to sort my data after clicking the search button. but the in search my data is not in alphabetical order.
don't know how to sort data in this search activity..show me the list as given in the string. want that the search activity show my data in alphabetical order.

```
public class Search extends Activity {

      protected static final Object TAG_DISTANCE = null;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    // List view
    private ListView lv;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6B8E23")));
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] ={"Atherosclerosis","Coranary Heart Disease","Stable Angina","Unstable Angina","Myocardial Infarction","Cardiac Risk of Non-Cardiac Surgery","Sinus Rhythms","Atrial Tachyarrhthmias",
             "Supraventricular Tachycardias","Ventricular Tachyarrhthmias","Sinoatrial Disease","Atrioventricular and Bundle Branch Block",
             "Peripheral Arterial Disease","Aortic Aneurysm","Aortic Dissection","Hypertension",
             "Rheumatic Heart Disease","Mitral Stenosis","Mitral Regurgitaion","Mitral Valve Prolapse","Aortic Stenosis","Aortic Regurgitation","Tricuspid Stenosis","Tricuspid Regurgitation","Pulmonary Stenosis","Pulmonary Regurgitation","Infective Endocarditis","Persistent Ductus Arteriosis","Conginital Heart Disease","Diseases of the Myocardium",
             "Diseases of the Pericardium"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_items, R.id.searchdisease,products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);



        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }



            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                Search.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
        Arrays.sort(product);
        for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
            System.out.println(products[i]);
```

And also

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in TextChanged.

Comment: It is just for update ur arrayadapter on textchange its optional.